# Get meta data from tumblr

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, meta

I would like to put open graph meta tags (og:image, og:description) to a database on my site from a tumblr blog. I tried to get meta tags from tubmlr with this code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.example.com");
//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
$meta = $metas->item($i);
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}
echo "Title: $title". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Description: $description". '<br/><br/>';
echo "Keywords: $keywords";
```

I know this code won't get the open graph code, but the problem is it doesn't get any meta. The code works fine with for exaple www.google.com but not with tumblr. 
How could I get the tumblr meta?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a sample tumblr URL you're trying? Because I copy/pasted your code and used www.tubmlr.com and got the title, description, and keywords back.

Comment: Really? I tried with www.tumblr.com and it times out. I don't know what could be the problem. It works with google for example

Comment: Here is the output I get. Title: `Sign up | Tumblr`, Description: `Post anything (from anywhere!), customize everything, and find and follow what you love. Create your own Tumblr blog today.`, Keywords: `tumblelog, blog, tumblog, tumbler, tumblr, tlog, microblog`. If you are having problems with that you might want to output some info from curl, [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). See what that has to say about your connection to tumblr.

Comment: I tried curl_getinfo() and also times out, doing nothing. With google.com it works perfectly. Don't know what could be the problem :/

Comment: It is working great... I had problem with the web hosting :/ Thank you ver much for you help.